# plotting 2 variable of different size in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, user-interface, plot

Am trying to plot 2 variable of different size length in matlab GUI using push button,
but because the variables are of different length it will not work,is there a way i can make it to plot.

```
d= pdist([x,y,z],'euclidean') ;  % value of my distance   
dd= 1:10:d;            % interval and end 'd' value                                 
FSL=-120;           %value of free space loss get from the GUI   
DFSL= 1:10:FSL         %interval and end at FSL value

plot(dd,DFSL)
```

The plot code didnt work coming back with an error "
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same lengths"

Comment: Are you trying to plot dd and DFSL against each other as an (x,y) pair? Or do you just want to see both variables plotted against their own index?

Comment: am trying to as (x,y) pair.Thanks

Comment: You can't plot two vectors of unequal lengths as an (x,y) pair, as the longer vector will run out of corresponding values in the shorter vector. If you know the index of the values in the longer vector that you want to compare, then: `plot(shortVec,longVec(index))` should work, where index is an integer vector the same length as shortVec, with no values greater than `numel(longVec)`.

Comment: You set the interval for dd and DFSL to 10. Why is this? Do you know  know that time x-vector for dd starts at 1 and ends at d?

Comment: yes i want it to plot  dd against DFSL at every 10 interval

Comment: @doresoom ,do you know how to get the index of the variable value?

Answer (score 1):

You can plot vectors of two different lengths, but not against each other. You have used the syntax

```
plot(x,y)
```

which means for every element in vector x, there should be a corresponding element in vector y. In your case, you do not have this, hence the error.

You can plot like this though:

```
plot(x)
figure;
plot(y)
```

If you are looking to plot them in a single plot, [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) will be useful.